# Convergent sequence on unit sphere

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose $x_n$ is a bounded sequence in a vector space $V$ with norm $||\cdot||$. Show that if:

$$\hat{x}_n=\frac{x_n}{||x_n||}\;\;\text{converges}\Rightarrow x_n\;\text{has a convergent subsequence}$$

---

**Thoughts:** Writing the limit on the sphere as $\hat{x}=x/||x||$ I would like to show that for large enough $M$ (bounding $||x_n||$), there are $n_0<n_1<\cdots$ such that

$$\frac{1}{M}||x_{n_k}-x||\leq ||\hat{x}_{n_k}-\hat{x}||\quad \forall k>K$$
First, is this even true? If so could can I show it?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing a hypothesis?  $\{v,2v,v,2v,v,2v, \dots \}$ is bounded with constant projection on the unit sphere, but has no hope of converging.

Comment: @EricTowers Oh sorry, yes I misquoted from memory: I need to show $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence. Will update now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The sequence of numbers $\| x_n\|$ is real and bounded, so it must contain a convergent subsequence by the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem.